# Interpreting the Intrinsic Scatter (dispersion)

Tags: regression, correlation, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, dispersion

I have some data with uncertainties on both the independent and the dependent parameter. I did a Hierarchical Bayesian Model to study whether there is a correlation between the dependent and the independent parameters. The result of the MCMC is:

$$ y = (0.13 \pm 0.03) + (-0.18 \pm 0.6)x + \epsilon $$

where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is the intrinsic scatter.

From MCMC, I estimated $\sigma = 0.05 \pm 0.02$.

I need help to interpret the intrinsic scatter and hence the correlation.

### My interpretation

- The slope of the line, taking into consideration the uncertainties, is nearly ZERO. Thus I can say that there is no correlation.
- Looking at the intrinsic scatter, the value on average is not small (but not big too, right?). So the data points do deviate a bit from the best fit line.

Is this the way to interpret my results?

Here's a graph of my data point. The red dotted line is the best fit line whereas the light red lines are samples from my MCMC chain.
[image]

Comment: What are the reported $\pm$ numbers in the parentheses, are they standard errors? If so, your slope seems to be 3 SEs from 0, *not* "nearly ZERO".

Comment: @gung The $\pm$ numbers are the $1\sigma$ uncertainties on the parameters. They were derived using MCMC.

Comment: @gung My main idea is to say that there is no correlation. It is clear from the graph and by plotting the samples from the MCMC chains. The slope = 0 lies in the interval $-0.18 \pm 0.6$.

Comment: My mistake, I misread it; I thought it was 0.06, not 0.6. I need to go to sleep.

Comment: @gung, I still need to double check that my interpretation of the intrinsic scatter is statistically correct. Sweet dreams :)